# Not able to play aac audio files on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, html5-audio

I have a page with this html :

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.aac" type="audio/aac" />
</audio>
```

It works on Firefox and Edge but it doesn't on IE11. My windows version is up to date and I saw it should be supported. I tried to change my settings to be sure ActiveX is enabled and it is.

I also tried with :

```
<audio controls="controls" src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.aac">
```

It doesn't works too.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try using type="audio/mp4"? I'm not sure that will work with your file but its worth a try

Comment: @ScottPowell yes I did an it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the sample code with IE 11 browser and I am able to produce the issue.

I try to check the documentation and found this information.

> Beginning with Windows Internet Explorer 9, any audio or video content
>   needs the correct mime type set on the server, or the files won't
>   play. Internet Explorer 9 supports MP3 audio, and MP4 audio and video.
>   WebM audio and video files can be supported by installing the WebM
>   components from The WebM project. The following table shows the
>   required settings for your web server to host these files correctly.
>   Microsoft Edge updates introduced WAV support.

[image]

Reference:

[audio element | audio object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/hh772923%28v=vs.71%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

you can see that .AAC format is not in the list but sites like MDN and CANIUSE shows that it is supported.

I also tried with audio type mp4 which also did not worked.

```html
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.aac" type="audio/mp4" />
</audio>
```

It also can be possible that it is some kind of bug with IE browser or issue is related with H.264 format.

As a work around, I suggest you to use mp3 file format which is working fine with IE 11.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg3" />
</audio>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I saw [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats) than aac files can be wrapped in an MP4 or ADTS containers. It's supposed to works when it's wrapped in a MP4 format. I suppose we can consider the AAC format as partially supported.